# Amazon S3 iOS Crypto class Android equivalent

Tags: android, ios, amazon-s3, cryptoapi

I am implementing an app using Amazon S3 File transfer on Android. The iOS app is already done. The iOS app calls

```
NSData   *body = [Crypto decrypt:tokenString key: keyFromServer];
```

To decrypt. The Crypto class is part of the AWS iOS SDK by Amazon. I am having a hard time to find the Android counterpart for Crypto class.
Please help.

Thanks
Ray